# Range of digits in Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have got this format of data

> *0179*1*A*500000000,M-00,R-12113

Regex is tested here http://regexstorm.net/tester

```
\*\d{4}\*\d{1}\*[ABCEFGHJKLMPRV]{1}(\*)\d+\,M-\d{2},R-\d{5}
```

This part `12113` should be 1-5 in length.

This part `500000000` shoul dbe 1-13 digits in length.

So I need to define a regex with a variable length for those parts. Any clue?

Comment: btw, your link didn't pull up a saved regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the appropiate quantifiers

```
\*\d{4}\*\d\*[ABCEFGHJKLMPRV](\*)\d{1,13}\,M-\d{2},R-\d{1,5}
```

{x,y} means atleast x and max y times.

For some better English explanation, just check any [regex reference](http://regexstorm.net/reference).

Comment: You could simplify it to `\*\d{4}\*\d\*[ABCEFGHJKLMPRV]\*\d{1,13}\,M-\d{2},R-\d{1,5}`